# Pandas cumsum + cumcount on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Aloha,

I have the following DataFrame

```
stores = [1,2,3,4,5]
weeks = [1,1,1,1,1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Stores' : stores,
                  'Weeks' : weeks})

df = pd.concat([df]*53)
df['Weeks'] = df['Weeks'].add(df.groupby('Stores').cumcount())

df['Target'] = np.random.randint(400,600,size=len(df)) 
df['Actual'] = np.random.randint(350,800,size=len(df)) 
df['Variance %'] = (df['Target'] - df['Actual']) / df['Target']
df.loc[df['Variance %'] >= 0.01, 'Status'] = 'underTarget'
df.loc[df['Variance %'] <= 0.01, 'Status'] = 'overTarget'
df['Status'] = df['Status'].fillna('atTarget')

df.sort_values(['Stores','Weeks'],inplace=True)
```

this gives me the following

`print(df.head())`

```
    Stores  Weeks   Target  Actual  Variance %  Status
0   1   1   430 605 -0.406977   overTarget
0   1   2   549 701 -0.276867   overTarget
0   1   3   471 509 -0.080679   overTarget
0   1   4   549 378 0.311475    underTarget
0   1   5   569 708 -0.244288   overTarget
0   1   6   574 650 -0.132404   overTarget
0   1   7   466 623 -0.336910   overTarget
```

now what I'm trying to do is do a cumulative count of Stores where they were either over or undertarget but reset when the status changes.

I thought this would be the best way to do this (and many variants of this) but this does not reset the counter.

```
s = df.groupby(['Stores','Weeks','Status'])['Status'].shift().ne(df['Status'])
df['Count'] = s.groupby(df['Stores']).cumsum()
```

my logic was to group by my relevant columns, and do a != shift to reset the cumsum

Naturally I've scoured lots of different questions but I can't seem to figure this out. Would anyone be so kind to explain to me what would be the best method to tackle this problem?

I hope everything here is clear and reproducible. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Expected Output

```
  Stores    Weeks   Target  Actual  Variance %  Status Count
0   1   1   430 605 -0.406977   overTarget             1
0   1   2   549 701 -0.276867   overTarget             2
0   1   3   471 509 -0.080679   overTarget             3
0   1   4   549 378 0.311475    underTarget            1  # Reset here as status changes
0   1   5   569 708 -0.244288   overTarget             1  # Reset again.
0   1   6   574 650 -0.132404   overTarget             2
0   1   7   466 623 -0.336910   overTarget             3
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: edited question = )!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `pd.Series.groupby()` after create the key by `cumsum`

```
s=df.groupby('Stores')['Status'].apply(lambda x : x.ne(x.shift()).ne(0).cumsum())
df['Count']=df.groupby([df.Stores,s]).cumcount()+1
```

Comment: you are a genius sir. Quick question, in my head (and this is probably why I could not get it to work) I was always grouping by the Week, why would this not need to be done in this instance?

Comment: @Datanovice since your week is unique for each of store, if you groupby week , you will get unique row , which means (store + week) can be a unique key for your sample df. so groupby does not work

Comment: Thanks! final Q why is `.ne(0)` from what I understand  `x : x.ne(x.shift())` returns a `true` or `false` boolean?

Comment: @Datanovice that is just like a coding style :-)